Azure DevOps Can't find the Build File
I use Azure DevOps with a self-hosted agent to build and deploy pipelines and releases to an Azure app service.  I have three of these that work great.  However, I have built a new app service and the release pipeline for it won't build.  I copied the pipeline and release pipeline to match the ones that work.  I also created a new service connection for the new app service.
The artifact builds and completes during the build pipeline.  The download task of the artifact is successful in the release pipeline. The naming conventions are accurate.  But, when the release pipeline attempts to open the zip file in the artifact, it doesn't find it.
The specific error is:
Error: No package found with the specified pattern: D:\x\xx\x\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

The only difference between the old and new scenarios is the new app service uses a managed identity. It doesn't seem like this would matter, but I have something wrong and can't figure it out.

After two days of frustration, I posted this question.  Five minutes later, I stumbled on the answer.  I reviewed the Release Pipeline and drilled down a couple of levels in the directory where the artifact is stored.  This has been unnecessary in previous pipelines, but it is what worked for this one.  My pipeline ran successfully!

Thanks for your help.  I have made the update.
